# Is "along" correct in "You were the best along with person X and Y"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

> You were the best *along* with person X and person Y.

When I want to tell someone that he was one of the best in the group of people, but not the only one, can I use the word *along*? Or is *together* or some other word more appropriate?

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Learners](http://ell.stackexhange.com).  ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of questions than ELU does.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, “You were the best along with person X and person Y” is acceptable but not wonderful; it also is acceptable with  *together* in place of *along*.  I think “You, X, and Y did best” or “You, X, and Y were best” or “You were among the best, along with X and Y” are better phrasings.

Unlike *were best*, the term *did best* suggests a distinction between the person and what they did.  The distinction is more explicit in “Your effort was among the best”.  Such a distinction may matter when a bad person is doing good work, or if you prefer to judge a person's work rather than the person.